# Reformulating $\arg\min |x|$.

Tags: optimization

Is it possible to reformulate next optimization problem  $\arg\min |x|$ in terms of constrained minimization problem with twice continuously differentiable functions.

As an example of such transformation: $\arg\min \max_{i-1,\dots,m} (a_i^T x + b_i)$ is equivalent to 
minimize t subject to $a_i^Tx + b_i \le t, i = 1, \dots, m$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try rewriting the absolute value as $|x|=\max\{x,-x\}$. Using the transformation you mention you are left with:

\begin{align}
\min &t \\
\text{s.t.}\\
x&\leq t\\
-x&\leq t.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\min &f(x) \\s.t.\\|g(x)|\leq 0\\
&\downarrow \\
\min &f(x)\\s.t.\\g(x)&\leq 0\\-g(x)&\leq0
\end{align}