# reformulating $\arg\min |x|^{1.5}$

Tags: optimization

I've asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/312401/23998). Essentially I have the same question for problem $\arg\min |x|^{1.5}$.
We can consider next variant $\arg\min t^{1.5}$ subject to $x\le t$
 and $-x \le t$. But $t^{1.5}$ is not twice continuously differentiable.

Intuitively  $|x|^{1.5}$ is "between" $|x|$ and $x^2$, so there should be nice formulation of optimization problem for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\min_x \ |x|^{3/2}$ may be written
$$
\min_{x,t} \ t^{3/2} \quad \text{s.t.} \ -t \leq x \leq t.
$$
Now this constraint is equivalent to $-t^3 \leq x^3 \leq t^3$. Define $s := t^{3/2}$. You have $t^3 = s^2$, so now you can rewrite your problem as
$$
\min_{x,s} \ s \quad \text{s.t.} \ -s^2 \leq x^3 \leq s^2.
$$